# Multiple apps for one purpose. Illegal?

Tags: facebook, web-crawler

Is anything illegal in having multiple Facebook apps for the same purpose? I'm doing thesis for bachelor degree in computer science on Distributed Facebook Crawling so it would be a disaster to base thesis on something that's not legal.

DISCLAIMER: thesis is only for scientific purpose and the idea is to develop try existing and develop new methods for scheduling.

Comment: Well, isn't "crawling" already very to close to "illegal" ...?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure. Think about http://hipset.com/.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, there is no any rule for what purpose app is made for. You can use for same or different purposes. (otherwise same type of games couldn't on facebook).

What do you mean by same purpose? I don't think facebook is checking for what purpose app is used unless anyone have reported it.

Comment: I think that you have to get a lot of information with smallest effort you can do. Facebook API has limits on some tables so one approach is to create multiple apps and work parallel.

Comment: Limit given to one app will be given to all apps. I don't know how can creating multiple apps will avoid limits. Can you explain that?

Comment: Nope, you won't avoid limits. 3apps * 600calls > 1app * 600calls :)